# Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Tags: php, функции, отладка

Помогите с кодом, с такой ошибкой решения у всех разные.

Ошибка:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in Drupal\content_parser\Form\ContentParserForm->parseUrl() (line 696 of ...).
```

Что не так с кодом?:

```
 public function parseUrl($url, $depth, $results, $options, $last, array &$context) {
    foreach (['urls', 'results', 'processed_urls'] as $key => $value) {
      if (!isset($context['results'][$key]) && $results[$key]) {
        $context['results'][$key] = $results[$key];
      }
      else {
        $context['results'][$key] = [];
      }
    }

    $context['message'] = $this->t('Парсинг страницы (@url) Уровень: @depth', [
      '@url' => $url,
      '@depth' => $depth,
    ]);

    $entity = $this->entity;

    $context['results']['processed_urls'][$url] = $url;

    if ($this->limit($context)) {
      return;
    }

    $entity->processUrl($url, $options, function ($result) use ($context) {
      $context['results']['results'][] = $result;
      return $this->limit($context);
    });

    if ($this->limit($context)) {
      return;
    }

    if ($depth < $entity->getDepth() && $doc) {
      foreach ($entity->findUrls($doc, $url) as $url_find) {
        if (!isset($context['results']['processed_urls'][$url_find])) {
          $context['results']['urls'][$url_find] = $url_find;
        }
      }
    }

    if ($last && $context['results']['urls']) {
      $this->createBatch($context['results']['urls'], ++$depth, $context['results'], $options);
    }
  }
```

Ошибка возникает в этой строке:

```
$context['results'][$key] = [];
```

Comment: А если подумать самому, нееаа? Или использовать поиск по нашему сайту, Гуглу, Яндексу?

Comment: Я забыл написать что я новичок в php, полный ноль, прочитал пару руководств но так и не понял даного кода. Поставил Eclips, код проходит валидацию . 

Пишет "Variable '$value' is never used" - означает что значение пустое и черз него ошибка?

Comment: Если вы не знаете английский - то вставьте текст в переводчик. Вам вернется "Переменная «$value» никогда не используется".